# Mysql two varchar column data range

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compare the inbetween value of two varchar column in mysql

i have a two columns col1 and col2 both are varchar type
both having alphanumeric values and i want to compare the provided value is in between or not

For Example 
col1 value is 'L7J0A1' and col2 value is 'L7J3B7'
and if i provided a this 'L7J0A2' value it should return the single row which range contains the this 'L7J0A2' value

```
SELECT * FROM gojit_postalcode_zone_mapping 
WHERE 'L7J0A1' BETWEEN from_postal_code AND to_postal_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because where you have your provided value 'L7J0A1' mysql is looking for a column name.
Judging by what I think you want this is how you would do it:

```
SELECT * FROM postalcode_zone_mapping WHERE col1 < 'L7J0A1' AND col2 > 'L7J0A1'
```

If you want it to be inclusive just use =< and >= instead.  If this doesn't accomplish I must be misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for reply
i tried using your suggetions actually i tried it many times its not giving me a exact row.

Comment: this should give you all rows where 'L7J0A1' is between the 2 values, if that is not what you want please clarify what you would like to accomplish as I must be misunderstanding you

Comment: It looks like you altered your question, but you still have the between backwards.  Where you have the value 'L7J0A1' you need to have a column name and where you have your column names you can have values.  It doesn't sound like that will accomplish your goal, so 'BETWEEN' isn't going to work for you.

Comment: I have a table Postal_mapping which columns are from_postal to_postal and zone
for one record from postal contains L7J0A1 and to_postal contains L7J3B7 and my input is L7J0A2

Comment: I have a table Postal_mapping which columns are from_postal to_postal and zone
for one record from postal contains L7J0A1 and to_postal contains L7J3B7 and my input is L7J0A2
so i want to check the provided postal code is in between or not

Comment: SELECT * FROM postal_mapping WHERE 'L7J0A2' >= from_postal  AND 'L7J0A2' <=to_postal;
SELECT * FROM postal_mapping WHERE  'L7J0A2' BETWEEN  from_postal AND to_postal;
SELECT * FROM postal_mapping WHERE from_postal =< 'L7J0A2' AND to_postal >= 'L7J0A2';
i tried with queries but i am not getting the Exact row
So i want to find out the input postal code is in between to these columns or not 
please suggest if you have any idea about that

Comment: What row are you wanting to return, I think the problem here is I don't understand what you are asking.  It sounds like you are wanting to return a single row but I am not sure what row you want.  The query I provided give you all the rows where the input postal code is between the "from" and "to" postal codes

Comment: I understand you want to find out if your postal code is between the 2 column values, but you are going to have multiple rows with these 2 values to compare against.  So I don't know what "exact row" you want.  If you want to find out if you input value is between any to_postalcode and from_postalcode value then just return the COUNT() of a field and if its > 1 then it does fall between at least 1 range of postal codes in your table.